# How can I remove these excess shrinkwrap faces?

Tags: modifiers, faces, shrinkwrap

I am trying to shrinkwrap a hex pattern onto a visor of a helmet im working on. While it has been successful, how can I remove the excess hexagons without having to manually delete and even better, without applying the modifier? I have used the HOPS shrinkwrap. [image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we want, we can mark those excess vertices by assigning them to a vertex group.  Selecting which ones we want is very easy; we can do it in a wireframe view, with a box select:

[image]

Once assigned, we can use a mask modifier to delete them, non-destructively, before or after the shrinkwrap:

[image]

If we don't even want to have to *mark* these verts with a vertex group, we can let Blender figure out the vertex group assignments.  The good verts are the ones that have been shrinkwrapped on to the face-- their distance from the surface of the mesh is 0.  So we can assign all other verts to a group using a vertex proximity modifier:

[image]

First, I assigned all vertices to Group.001.  Then I set up my vertex weight proximity modifier-- between my shrinkwrap and mask modifiers in the stack-- to measure proximity from geometry/faces, and I told it to assign anything further than 0.002 a weight of 1.0, and anything closer than 0.001 a weight of 0.0.  This can be improved to any arbitrary level of precision, but I figure 0.001 precision is enough.